# Approximate unit for the algebra C*(h) consisting of projectors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let E be a Hilbert C*-module over some C*-algebra  and let $h \in K(E)$. Due to B. Blackadar's, "K-Theory for Operator algebras" Thm. 17.11.4 for a separable C*-algebra $A$, represented by elements of $B(E)$, it is possible to construct a countable approximate unit $\{u_n\}$ contained in $C^*(h)$, such that $\{u_n\}$ is quasicentral for $A$ and $u_{n+1} u_n=u_n$. The question is: is it always possible to make $u_n$ be projectors (or, at least, idempotents). The question seems to be obvious if $E$ is just a Hilbert space, but I'm not sure for Hilbert modules.

Comment: Nice question. Would be even nicer if you would edit the question and put dollars in around the math.

Comment: Personally, I think that the question is sufficiently "symbol-light" that there is no need here to hit everything with jsMath. Most readers likely to contribute to this question are IMHO capable of a certain amount of `internal LaTeX parsing'

Comment: Here's a link to the Theorem you cite: http://books.google.com/books?id=_YQvFHnD6bQC&lpg=PA165&dq=blackadar%2017.11.4&pg=PA165#v=onepage&q=&f=false.

Comment: @Yemon: But we built computers so that they do our work for us! 

Comment: It seems that really, for this question, Blackadar is actually following Pedersen, "C*-algebras and their automorphism groups", 3.12.14 (no Google preview).  Also, h is absolutely NOT an arbitrary element in K(E): it seems that, at least, we want h to be "strictly positive": I think this is equivalent to hK(E)h being dense in K(E).

Comment: Yes, I've realized that I have to write that H is strictly positive when I was already out of keyboard and Internet connection. Thanks! 

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Matthew.  It's a shame that Pedersen isn't in print anymore, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  In fact, K(E) need not even contain any nonzero projections.  Take a (nontrivial) C*-algebra B with no nonzero projections<sup>1</sup> and take E=B as a right module over B with inner product 〈a,b〉=a*b.  Then K(E)≅B, as mentioned in [Example 13.2.4 (a)](http://books.google.com/books?id=_YQvFHnD6bQC&lpg=PA109&ots=w9jB2qq8x4&dq=blackadar%252013.2.4&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q=&f=true) in Blackadar, and proved for instance as [Proposition 2.2.2 (i)](http://books.google.com/books?id=s_pNcoqXwFoC&lpg=PA203&dq=manuilov%2520troitsky&lr=&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q=&f=true) in Manuilov and Troitsky.  (Note that in this case K(E) [also has no nonzero idempotents](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16943/reference-needed-for-every-idempotent-in-a-c-algebra-is-similar-to-a-hermitian).)

**Edit:** I removed an overly complicated comment on the Hilbert space case, forgetting to take into account that h is strictly positive, and in particular positive.  I added a comment on trouble that may arise even in this case.

In the case when E is a Hilbert space over B=ℂ, taking into account the fact that h is self-adjoint, C*(h) is the C*-algebra generated by a self-adjoint compact operator, and therefore the spectral projections of h provide an approximate identity {u<sub>n</sub>} consisting of increasing projections.  Because h is *strictly* positive, its range is dense, so this will be a sequence of projections converging weakly to the identity operator.  However, this approximate identity need not be quasicentral for A⊆B(E).  E.g., suppose you have u<sub>n</sub> equal to the projection onto the span of the first n elements of an orthonormal basis.  If S is the unilateral shift with respect to that basis, then ||u<sub>n</sub>S−Su<sub>n</sub>|| = 1 for all n, so {u<sub>n</sub>} is not quasicentral for C*(S).  Pedersen uses the Hahn-Banach theorem and the axiom of choice to show the existence of a quasi-central approximate identity in the closed convex hull of {u<sub>n</sub>}, but you typically will not be able to find one consisting of projections, even in the Hilbert space case.

<sup>1</sup> E.g., take B to be C<sub>0</sub>(X) for some noncompact, locally compact, connected space X, or if you prefer simple algebras see [Blackadar's 1980 paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2042420).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I feel sorry for asking such primitive questions. Actually I just would like to rewrite the Blackadar's theorem for my own purposes, namely to construct such $D$ that I'll have an upper estimation for $\|[D,a_j]\|$.

As for the case of Hilbert space, the spectrum of the compact operator  $h$ is then just a sequence of points on R tending to 0, so, as I thought, we may just use functional calculus to makefinite-dimensional projectors.

Comment: Good point, that's probably a simpler way to get the approximate identity in the Hilbert space case.  I haven't thought much about it, but the strict positivity implies quasicentrality of the approximate identity in this case, doesn't it?

Comment: I thought about it more and realized that the answer to my question is no.  I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Kolya Ivankov, by the way, there is no reason to apologize for your question.

Comment: Maybe this is a little off topic, but Manuilov has done some work on defining generalized "eigenvalues" for compact operators on Hilbert A-modules, in case A is a von Neumann algebra. This can be found in the book by Manuilov and Troitsky on Hilbert C* modules or in the paper by Manuilov "Diagonalizing operators in Hilbert modules over C*-algebras".
